# 'Load new answers' banner - phantom new answers

Tags: support, new-answers

I was adding an answer to [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8914/how-do-search-engines-handle-hyphenated-words), and the banner popped up saying "1 new answers as been posted - load new answers". When clicking the link, nothing loaded and the banner disappeared.

A few seconds later, the banner reappeared. This kept happening and I clicked a few times but no answer ever loaded. After I submitted my answer there was no additional answer, just the one already before I started mine.

Perhaps someone posted an answer and promptly deleted it before I clicked "load new answers", but the banner should not keep appearing unless there is still a new answer.

Comment: Wait until a >10k user comes along. There may have been an answer added that was later deleted

Comment: @Earlz: Yes that's what I mentioned in the question - but if it was deleted it should not keep saying there are new answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you have the question open in two tabs, or reach it by clicking the back button in your browser, or interrupt its loading at any point? All of those things have confused the banner from my end, before.